# Check heroku deployment is up to date

Tags: git, heroku

I have a heroku remote named production. In order to push the app up to production I use

```
git push production master
```

Before doing so, I would like to check if the version on production is up to date. I have tried

```
git diff master..production
```

but that is the incorrect syntax. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe just to do

```
git push production master
```

if it is up to date, you receive the response:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

otherwise it pushes the new slug up to heroku.